# How to specify that I want an exact match between strings in Botium Box (Watson Assistant)

Tags: automated-tests, chatbot, botium-box

I am having the following issue while testing the dialogues of my Watson Assistant skill in Botium Box: it looks like some test cases pass with success even though there is not an exact match between the *expected* response and the *actual* response of the bot. It seems that a test case passes successfully if the *expected* text is a substring in the actual answer from the bot.

Is there a way to specify that I want a exact match?

Example:
If the expected response is: **"Hello my name is John, how can help you?"** but the actual response is: **"Hello my name is John, how can help you today?"**

botium box will mark this test cased as passed.

Is there a way to specify that I want an exact match between the two strings?

Answer (score 0):

The default matching mode in Botium is *wildcardIgnoreCase*, which is a kind of simple regular expression mode (* matches everything) - more in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE). This mode does substring matching as well, but you can change it in the [Advanced Scripting Settings](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/60817419/What+are+the+Advanced+Scripting+Settings+in+Botium+Box) of Botium Box.

Instead of configuring the matching mode globally, you can also decide to use on of the [text asserters](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/109477893/Text+Asserters), so the test case would look like this:

```
asserter

#me
hello

#bot
TEXT_CONTAINS_ALL_IC hello|my name is john
```

I prepared a [repl.it](https://repl.it/@FlorianTreml/replit-botium-bindings-pinolo-1) as demo.